# How to run Android Studio 3.0 from command line as root user in Mac

Tags: android, macos, permissions, root

I need to run Android Studio 3.0 in root user to give permission to SDK manager (as SDK Manager is no longer Standalone) to install components to the root directory.

If you are getting `Permission Denied` errors for any component installation, this can be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have installed Android Studio in the default Applications directory, this is where it will be. Else you can cd into it's path

`cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/`

then run it as root user by executing

`sudo ./studio`

Comment: shorter `sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

Comment: shorter is better, thank you Naibaba and Junaid